# Accepting and sending API for Ethereum

Tags: php

Is there any good API for accepting and sending Ethereum like blocktrail for bitcoin ?
Why is working with Ethereum so complicated?

Comment: For what exactly you need the API. Have you checked web3.js?

Comment: +1 for  "Why is working with Ethereum so complicated?" :D

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum works differently so there is less need for APIs for accepting and sending Ethereum. Working with Ethereum is not complicated, it just requires different approach than other cryptocurrencies. You need to throw away some false assumptions and relearn different concepts.

Ethereum has [Web3 JavaScript API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API). The interaction with Ethereum happens on the client side, in the web browser, without insecure server processing being in-between. Usually Web3 is run in a browser through a plugin like MetaMask, people are using decentralized browsing application like Parity or you just use EtherScan.io API. In this case, the user is directly connected to Ethereum network, not to your server.

There is less need for server-side payment processing, because smart contracts and [Solidity events](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events) can be used as a signal of completed user completed operations, like payments. Listening to [the events can be done over JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getlogs).